# Tampermonkey script for YouTube not loading when opening videos linked from YouTube website

Tags: javascript, youtube, tampermonkey

I wrote a Tampermonkey script to replace the "___ days/months/years ago" field on YouTube video descriptions with the actual date, the way things used to be. The script works great when opening a YouTube URL directly via `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`, but it won't execute when clicking a video link on the YouTube website, such as from search results or the homepage.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTube Date Changer
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      2024-01-13
// @description  Replaces the "___ days/months/years ago" with the actual upload date in the video description
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/watch?*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=tampermonkey.net
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-end
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    function run () {
        var longdate = document.querySelector("div#info-strings yt-formatted-string");
        if (longdate) {
            var str = longdate.innerHTML;
            var shortdate = document.getElementsByClassName("style-scope yt-formatted-string bold")[2];
            shortdate.innerHTML = str;
        } else {
            setTimeout(run,250);
        }
    }
    run();
})();
```

This appears to happen because YouTube internally loads videos from its website instead of making a new request for the video URL. (Note the progress bar that shoots across the top of the window after clicking a video link on YouTube.) I don't think Tampermonkey ever sees the `@match` in my script.

I can work around this behavior by opening video links in a new window, but that doesn't really solve the problem. I see two solutions:

1. Force YouTube (through additional userscripts?) to open all videos links as if they were new requests; or
2. Use a different method of triggering the Tampermonkey script by detecting when the video loads, not when the URL changes.

I tried researching these two ideas, but I haven't had any luck. I'd prefer #2 but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: You could also use a `MutationObserver`, and monitor for changes - either in the entire DOM (if your video container is not always there), or the video container itself (if it's always there). There could be performance issues with this, depending on the amount and frequencies of changes, though. For example, if you're monitoring the `body`, it could change in ways which are irrelevant for your needs - scrolling down to read comments, replies, etc - and that would trigger your mutation observer.

Comment: Really helpful! I looked into `MutationObserver`, but this seemed a little more complicated than what I needed for the reasons @FiddlingAway mentioned. @Wongjn's link was helpful to point me to the correct vocabulary (HTML5 History API). I ended up changing `@match` to the root YT domain and adding an event listener (with 1000 ms timeout) for `yt-update-title` to trigger my script. Thanks!